# Expected value of random walk with different probabilities

Tags: probability, expected-value, independence, random-walk

Let $n$ be a positive integer. Consider a random walk with $S_n=1+\sum^n_{i=1}X_i$, where the random i.i.d. steps $X_i$ take values $-1,0,2$ with probabilities $1/9,1/9,7/9$ respectively.

I would like to calculate $E(S_n)$. My attempt:

$$E(S_n)=E\left(1+\sum^n_{i=1}X_i\right)=1+\sum^n_{i=1}E(X_i)$$ $$=1+n[(-1)1/9+(0)1/9+(2)7/9]=1+(n)\frac{13}{9}$$

Would this be correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is correct. The only thing you use here is linearity of expectation.

Remark: Furthermore, there is no need for independence here.