# Determine when the random walk terminates

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables, expected-value, independence, random-walk

Consider a random walk with $S_n=\sum^n_{i=1}X_i$, where the random i.i.d. steps $X_i$ take values $-1,0,2$ with probabilities $1/9,1/9,7/9$ respectively. Set $S_0=1$.

The walk terminated whenever it either steps on the right boundary at $40$ or oversteps it by $1$ (i.e, terminates at $41$). The left boundary at $0$ is reflecting: whenever it is reached, the next step is either $1$ or $3$, with probabilities $\frac{2}{9}$ and $\frac{7}{9}$, respectively.

I would like to determine the expected time until the walk terminates.

I have calculated the expected value of the random walk in this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4222833/expected-value-of-random-walk-with-different-probabilities), however I have no idea how to answer when it will terminate. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Because of the reflection at the left boundary I don't think you have the correct generating function for this problem.

Comment: what question? the link seems to be broken?